# Proving inequality with multiple gaussian brackets

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm having trouble proving some inequality. I checked multiple values for $b,h$ with Excel and it seems to be true. Do you have some idea on how to prove it?

Let $b,h$ be natural numbers with:

- $b\geq h\geq 6$
- $n=hb$

$$
    \bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rceil-\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{2}\bigg\rceil\leq\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{4}-\frac{h}{2}\bigg\rfloor
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be integers with $a,b\ge 6$, and let $n=ab$.

**Claim:**
$$
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rfloor
+
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rceil
-
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{2}\bigg\rceil
\le
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{4}-\frac{a}{2}\bigg\rfloor
$$
**Proof:**

Defining $P,Q$ by
\begin{align*}
P&=
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rfloor
+
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rceil
-
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{2}\bigg\rceil
\\[4pt]
Q&=
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{4}-\frac{a}{2}\bigg\rfloor
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
our goal is to show that$\;P\le Q$.

Since $a,b\ge 6$, we can write
\begin{align*}
a&=\;6+x\\[4pt]
b&=\;6+y\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers.

Considering $xy$,$\;\text{mod}\;12$, we can write
$$
xy\,=12k+r
$$
where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $r\in\{0,...,11\}$.

Expanding $n$, we get
\begin{align*}
n&=\;\,
ab
\\[4pt]
&=\;
(6+x)(6+y)
\\[4pt]
&=\;
36+6x+6y+xy
\\[4pt]
&=\;
36+6x+6y+12k+r
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so for $P$ we get
\begin{align*}
P\;\;\;\;{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\;
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rfloor
+
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{3}\bigg\rceil
-
\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{2}\bigg\rceil
\\[8pt]
{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\left(12+2x+2y+4k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rfloor\right)\\[2pt]
&{\mathbf{+}}\left(12+2x+2y+4k+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rceil\right)\\[2pt]
&{\mathbf{-}}\left(18+3x+3y+6k+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{2}\bigg\rceil\right)\\[8pt]
{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;6+x+y+2k
+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rfloor
+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rceil
-\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{2}\bigg\rceil\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and for $Q$ we get
\begin{align*}
Q\;\;\;\;{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\;
\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{4}-\frac{a}{2}\bigg\rfloor
\\[4pt]
{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\;
\bigg\lfloor\frac{36+6x+6y+12k+r}{4}-\frac{6+x}{2}\bigg\rfloor
\\[4pt]
{\mathbf{=}}&\;\;\;\;\;
\bigg\lfloor
6+x+{\small{\frac{3}{2}}}y+3k+\frac{r}{4}
\bigg\rfloor
\\[4pt]
{\mathbf{\large{\ge}}}&\;\;\;\;\;
6+x+y+3k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{4}\bigg\rfloor
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence we get
\begin{align*}
Q-P\;\;\;\;{\mathbf{\large{\ge}}}
&\;\;\;\;\;\left(6+x+y+3k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{4}\bigg\rfloor\right)\\[2pt]
&{\mathbf{-}}\left(6+x+y+2k
+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rfloor
+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rceil
-\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{2}\bigg\rceil
\right)\\[6pt]
{\mathbf{=}}
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;k+\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{4}\bigg\rfloor
-\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rfloor
-\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rceil
+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{2}\bigg\rceil
\\[6pt]
{\mathbf{\large{\ge}}}
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{4}\bigg\rfloor
-\bigg\lfloor\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rfloor
-\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{3}\bigg\rceil
+\bigg\lceil\frac{r}{2}\bigg\rceil
\\[4pt]
{\mathbf{\large{\ge}}}
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
by direct evaluation for $r=0,...,11$.

Thus we have$\;Q-P\ge 0$, so $P\le Q$, as was to be shown.